# How to distinguish between ETH & ETC Node

Tags: go-ethereum, node-discovery, rlpx

I'm using the go-ethereum code (mainly discover (discv4) and rlpx) to write a node discovery tool.

The Programm is using discv4 to discover nodes on the internet and putting the discovered nodes into a que.

A different subroutine then pulls a node from the que and does the hole handshake thing to pass the "HELLO (0x00)" Message. So I get the Capabilities, Name of the Software that the Node is running, OS, ... .

Now I would like distinguish if node is actually a ETH or ETC node.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to differentiate between ETH & ETC peers at the P2P layer due to the fact that most client implement eth/63, which would defines STATUS 0x00 as

> [protocolVersion: P, networkId: P, td: P, bestHash: B_32, genesisHash:
>   B_32]

As ETC / ETH have identical genesis hashes and network IDs, it would be impossible to tell them apart from the ENR / Handshakes

[EIP-2124](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2124) attempts to resolve this by introducing "ForkID" into the `STATUS 0x00`. This is only implemented in Geth (see [HERE](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/93422e9d15063f707c381cd25758d6a34daece18/eth/peer.go#L448), and most ETC nodes would not be sending this packet.